# Second quantization, field operators and wave functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory

I'm trynig to learn QFT on my own and I have realized that I don't understand basics about second quantization even after reading almost all "Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur", some Peskin and Schroesder and watching some YouTube videos . So I have following questions:

- Why in second quantiztaion we use commutation relations on fields operators and momentum densities operators, insted of applying some kind of commutation relations on position and momentum operators that will be acting on Fock space? And why on Earth we are to do it that way?
- Why are field operators often compared to position operators? I mean specially Eq. 2.23 from Peskin and Schroesder (I don't know also why SHO Hamiltonian above holds in this case). I also don't understand how and why wave functions are interpreted in equations of motion such as Klein-Gordon equation as fields operators.

**PS:** Can someone send me a link to some good proof of spin-statistics theorem?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please be aware that posts are supposed to ask *one* question, not thirteen of them.

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Physics Amatour! I've voted to close your question for the "Needs more focus" reason. Also, you might find the following link helpful: [How do I ask a good question?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - *Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!*

Comment: I remember that ppl claim the peskin schroeder part is wrong